# Обратное построчное считывание файла

Tags: файлы, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать обратное считывание файла по строкам?

Comment: Аналогично обратному считыванию по блокам + поиск в очередном блоке символа `'\n`` от конца к началу.

Comment: А можете показать считывание по блокам?

Comment: Берете размер файла. 

Делите на размер блока (например 4096) -> получаете N (номер последнего бока).

Читаете блоками

    for (i = N; i >=0; --i) { 
      // не помню, как на Java
      // а так позиционируемся в Си
      lseek (fd, i * BLOCK_SIZE, SEEK_SET);
      int l = read(fd, buf, BLOCK_SIZE);   // а так читаем байты блока
      .... 
    }

Только у Вас возможна еще одна "проблема". Кодировка символов в файле (если UCS-2 (это внутреннее представление в Java), то каждый символ 2 байта), иначе скорее всего один).

Помятуя о Вашем "гигафайле" я взял бы BLOCK_SIZE побольше (скажем, 65536

Comment: а как делить на блоки?и выводить определенный блок на экран?

Comment: Делить ???

    long last_block_n = filesize / BLOCK_SIZE;

--

@Sergey4590, если Вы пишите программу для \*nix (и без Java никак), то IMHO Вам проще всего воспользоваться выводом `tail -n`, которую надо запускать раз в 30 секунд и перекидывать ее вывод на экран.

Comment: Я пишу на netbeans

Comment: В линуксе и в винде? Или Вам обязательно кроссплатформенно?

    кроссплатформенно

У меня комментарии закончились (лимит-с....)

--

@Sergey4590, посмотроите на [Class RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), там есть методы `.seek(long pos)` и `.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`, которые видимо Вам и нужны в Java.

Comment: кроссплатформенно

Comment: http://apache-mirror.rbc.ru/pub/apache//commons/io/binaries/commons-io-2.4-bin.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@Sergey4590](/users/8142/sergey4590)](/users/8142/sergey4590), у меня комментарии закончились. Лимит-с...

Перенесу часть текста из предыдущих комментариев.

---

```
как реализовать обратное считывание файла по строкам?
```

Аналогично обратному считыванию по блокам + поиск в очередном блоке символа `'\n`` от конца к началу.

Берете размер файла.
Делите на размер блока (например 4096) -> получаете N (номер последнего бока).
Читаете блоками.

Только у Вас возможна еще одна "проблема". Кодировка символов в файле (если UCS-2 (это внутреннее представление в Java), то каждый символ 2 байта), иначе скорее всего один).

Помятуя о Вашем "гигафайле" я взял бы BLOCK_SIZE побольше (скажем, 65536)

[[@Sergey4590](/users/8142/sergey4590)](/users/8142/sergey4590), если Вы пишите программу для *nix (и без Java никак), то IMHO Вам проще всего воспользоваться выводом tail -n, которую надо запускать раз в 30 секунд и перекидывать ее вывод на экран.

```
Я пишу на netbeans

кроссплатформенно
```

---

Посмотроите на [Class RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), там есть методы `.seek(long pos)` и `.read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`, которые видимо Вам и нужны в Java.

А для получения размера вызывайте `.length()` из [Class File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, вот есть файл
File myfile=new File("C:/file.txt");
Как его разделить на части,например по 1мб и вывести последнюю часть на экран?

Comment: Давно не писал на Java и возможности проверить нет, но что-то в таком духе

     final int MByte = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
     byte [] buffer = new byte[Mbyte];
     int  buflen = 0;
     try {
         RandomAccessFile fd = new RandomAccessFile(myfile, "r");
         fd.lseek((myfile.length() / Mbyte) * Mbyte);
         buflen = fd.read(buffer, 0, Mbyte);
         // теперь в buffer[] последние buflen байт из последнего мегабайта файла
     } catch(IOException ioex) {
        ...
     } catch(FileNotFoundException fex) {
        ...
     }

А лучше, спросите у кого-нибудь, кто сейчас в Java...

Comment: ясно,спасибо